# How can I properly group and minimize style code for UITextfields?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

I'm trying to implement a standard universal styling of my text fields based strictly on the login/sign up fields.

So, I designed them all to be identical, but I think that I'm reusing a lot of code that can be condensed and maybe used in a variable? I'm not sure how to do so.

The way it is works, but i'm sure it can be done better than this. I'm almost certain there's a way to minimize this code for better practice.

I'm still learning, so I really want to learn better practice in dev.

Here's an example of my sign up view & the styling of the fields:

```
class JoinVC: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {`

    @IBOutlet weak var enterEmailTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var enterPasswordTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var enterNameTextField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Field Border Corner + Width
        self.enterEmailTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 24.0
        self.enterEmailTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1.5
        self.enterPasswordTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 24.0
        self.enterPasswordTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1.5
        self.enterNameTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 24.0
        self.enterNameTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1.5
        // ...

        // Field Placeholder ColorEnter
        var placeholderEnterEmail = NSAttributedString(string: "Enter Email", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue:255/255, alpha: 0.6)])
        var placeholderEnterPass = NSAttributedString(string: "Choose Password", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue:255/255, alpha: 0.6)])
        var placeholderEnterName = NSAttributedString(string: "Choose Username", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue:255/255, alpha: 0.6)])

        enterEmailTextField.layer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(20, 0, 0);
        enterPasswordTextField.layer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(20, 0, 0);
        enterNameTextField.layer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(20, 0, 0);
        // ...

        // Text Field Border color
        var borderColor : UIColor = UIColor( red: 255, green: 255, blue:255, alpha: 0.8 )
        self.enterPasswordTextField.layer.borderColor = borderColor.CGColor; enterEmailTextField.attributedPlaceholder = placeholderEnterEmail;
        self.enterEmailTextField.layer.borderColor = borderColor.CGColor; enterPasswordTextField.attributedPlaceholder = placeholderEnterPass;
        self.enterNameTextField.layer.borderColor = borderColor.CGColor; enterNameTextField.attributedPlaceholder = placeholderEnterName;
    // ...


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I have solved this before, especially if all text fields in the project are:

1. Always going to have identical attributes,
2. Always going to be created from the storyboard

is to subclass `UITextField` and apply the attributes in `-awakeFromNib`:

```
class KBTextField: UITextField {
    let myAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue:255/255, alpha: 0.6)]
    let mySublayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(20, 0, 0)
    let myBorderColor = UIColor( red: 255, green: 255, blue:255, alpha: 0.8 )

    override func awakeFromNib () {
        self.layer.sublayerTransform = mySublayerTransform
        self.layer.borderColor = myBorderColor.CGColor
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 24.0
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1.5
        self.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: self.placeholder!, attributes: myAttributes)
    }
}
```

Then you can just set the class right on the storyboard (to `KBTextField`, in this case) and it will take care of all your attributes automatically.

This way, you can ensure that all `KBTextField`s in your app look identical, as long as you create them through the storyboard.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, being that I can just reuse the class on the fields in which i wish to target! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

easy solution for reusable code is a handler

```
  func setupTextField(textField : UITextField, placeHolderString: String)
  {
    let borderColor = UIColor( red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue:1.0, alpha: 0.8 )
    textField.layer.cornerRadius = 24.0
    textField.layer.borderWidth = 1.5
    textField.layer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(20, 0, 0);
    textField.layer.borderColor = borderColor.CGColor;
    textField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: placeHolderString, attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue:255/255, alpha: 0.6)])

  }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setupTextField(enterEmailTextField, placeHolderString: "Enter Email")
    setupTextField(enterPasswordTextField, placeHolderString: "Choose Password")
    setupTextField(enterNameTextField, placeHolderString: "Choose Username")
  }
```

Note: UIColor values must be in the range of 0.0 to 1.0

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Extension functionality](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html).
Just create an `Extension` of `UITextField` an place your code into that `Extension`
(easy tutorial [here](https://www.iphonelife.com/blog/31369/swift-programming-101-power-extensions))

Ex:

```
extension UITextField
{
    func setPlaceholderColorAndString(pholder: String, color: UIColor)
    {
        self.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string:pholder,
            attributes:[NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color])
    }

    func setupField()
    {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 24.0
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1.5
    }
}
```

Then in your code you can use it like:

```
self.enterEmailTextField.setPlaceholderColorAndString(pholder: "Enter Email", color: UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue:255/255, alpha: 0.6)
self.enterEmailTextField.setupField()
self.enterPasswordTextField.setPlaceholderColorAndString(pholder: "Enter Password", color: UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue:255/255, alpha: 0.6)
self.enterPasswordTextField.setupField()
```

And so on. Of course the above snippet it's only to give you an idea how using it, you can improve it a lot to fit your needs.